# Relation between ULA complexes and universally locally acyclic morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a complex of sheaves (in some appropriately defined sheaf-theoretic context) on $X$.

One has the notion of universal local acyclicity (ULA) of $\mathcal{F}$ with respect to $f$, which may be found in Braverman and Gaitsgory's paper "Geometric Eisenstein series". This is a pretty involved and technical definition so I will not attempt to reproduce it here. On the other hand, there is a notion of (universally local) acyclicity for the morphism $f$ itself. For example, one could require that the unit of an adjunction is an isomorphism.

My question is: what, if anything, does the ULA property of a sheaf have to do with acyclicity of a morphism? For example, if $f$ itself is universally locally acyclic then is every sheaf on $X$ also ULA?

Comment: ULA is first defined for complexes, then for maps in SGA, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0GJP — does this answer what you want?